# Does CiviVolunteer expose fields to webforms?

Tags: webform-civicrm, 4.7, civivolunteer

Currently working with CiviVolunteer, and some of the functionality is very useful for our project.  We are going to sign volunteers in to our events using a webform.  But no CiviVolunteer fields seem to be exposed to webforms - for example, volunteer role.  I am beginning to realise this extension is rather 'stand alone' and not really integrated with Civi - or have I missed something? I know that I can add custom fields to the Volunteer contact type, but I want to access the basic volunteer fields (like role) in a webform.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - the answer is 'no' there is indeed no CiviVolunteer - Webform Civicrm integration yet and much of our current efforts on the Webform CiviCRM project are directed towards a prototype version for D8;